# Android Chrome Custom Tab no access for Return Url

Tags: android

I have tried Chrome Custom Tab for SSO login to get call back URL I am able to launch the Custom Tab but I am not able to access the return URL after login.

I have used Following code read return URL

[Login Url](https://login.abc.com.my/def/login.aspx?pid=hij&ReturnUrl=com.abc.def://hostname)

```
<intent-filter android:label="abc">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="com.abc.def" android:host="hostName" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Activity**

```
try{
    if(null != getIntent()) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Uri data = intent.getData();

    }else {
        System.out.println("null intent found");
    }
}catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Marking your own question as a personal favourite doesn't help to get better answers.